# Divisibility: $2^n a+1\mid c^n+1\ \forall n\in \mathbb{N}\implies a=1$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have a very difficult problem that I cannot make any progress with. Here it is:

Let $a,c$ be fixed positive integers. Prove that if $2^n a+1$ divides $c^n+1$ for all positive integers $n$, then $a=1$ and $c=2^k$ for some odd positive integer $k$.

Thanks for any help,

Arkan

EDIT: As Calvin Lin pointed out, $a,c$ are positive integers.

Answer (score 1):

In fact if $a$, $b$, $\alpha$, $\beta$, $u$ and $v$ are non zero integers (with $|a|\not=1$ and $|b|\not=1$) such that $\alpha a^n+u \, | \, \beta b^n+v$, for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ large enough, then we can find a positive integer $k$ such that $b=a^k$ and $(-\alpha)^kv+\beta u^k=0$.

Have a look **[here](http://www.les-mathematiques.net/phorum/read.php?5,908119)** for more details (in french).

blaaang